# Hash English words used for lookups in a NoSQL Datastore?

Tags: database, hash, nosql, amazon-web-services, datastore

I am building a search engine. I am using NoSQL variety key-value datastores, specifically Amazon SimpleDB, and not a regular RDBMS. I have a table of URLs that point to web pages. I think I need to build another table which can be used to look up which pages contain a given English word.

The structure of this table is: `Search (String word, String URL)` and my queries would look like `select from Search where word = "foo"`

**Should I hash the words before storing them and for lookup?**  I. e. should I use a table: `Search (String word_hash, String URL)` and use queries like `select from Search where word = "acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8"`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The jury is out there for the general case. While it seems that the database would hash internally, there is definitely an important counter-example: BigTable that has it listed as a specific benefit that URL keys such as "com.example.foo/*.html" would cluster together to make it easier to build the Google search index. (see the bigtable paper for details).

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are doing this as an exercise, don't build your own. Use [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or something similar.

If this *is* an exercise, points for ambition! A search engine is a big project.

I don't see any value in hashing the words yourself. The hash table already does that internally (it's a *hash* table). Later on you might want to do basic spelling corrections, or allow "books" to also match "book", for example, and at that point it will help to have plain text words.

Comment: Does Amazon SimpleDB do the hashing internally?  Do other persistence providers such as AppEngine, etc. do the same?

Comment: Yes, they all do, but it's an implementation detail. They are (conceptually) big online hash table's (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

Comment: To answer your original question specifically, no, don't hash your strings before storing them.

Comment: Hi Graham, I am still not sure of your answer. (It's the only one I haven't yet accepted. I'm upvoting it though.) Say my strings happen to be such that most hash to the same key under the nosql datastore hash function. This seems to allow the possibility that perhaps some nosql datastores might leave hashing to the user? In general this would not be true so it seems that they would hash to avoid mistreating the common case. Either way, I think the main missing piece is any references to authoritative documentation, or a deeper analysis. At the moment it sounds like it is just your word. Thnx!

Comment: If your keys hash to the same bucket in the underlying store, there's just several keys in the bucket. No problem. That's irrelevant to your question, I should not have mentioned the underlying store's hashing, I think that is confusing you. Pretend it's a black box. You put in strings and urls, you get them back. You can put in hashes, the store doesn't care.

Comment: i understand. i just wish i'd get a reference to the same statement from a mainstream provider. i. e. it's a black box to you as much as to me so only a provider of such a box or a document of a generally accepted principle of such stores would help. thanks again for the explanation.

Comment: Amazon DynamoDB, the latest mainstream NoSQL offering clearly states: 'Choose a hash attribute that ensures that your workload is evenly distributed across hash keys. For example, "Customer ID" is a good hash key, while "Game ID" would be a bad choice if most of your traffic relates to a few popular games.' (contrary to your answer)